# Routes starting and ending in the US refuse to go through Canada

Tags: here-api

For routes that start and end in the US, HERE fails to suggest a route that goes through Canada even when I choose 'mode=fastest', and via Canada would clearly be the fastest route (traffic disabled).

e.g. Detroit to Buffalo

- [HERE We Go](https://wego.here.com/directions/drive/1145-Griswold-St,-Detroit,-MI-48226,-United-States:42.33239,-83.04887/207-Chadduck-Ave,-Buffalo,-NY-14207,-United-States:42.95594,-78.90584?map=42.14539,-81.15244,9,normal&msg=207%20Chadduck%20Ave)
- HERE Routing API gives the same as HERE We Go. I use traffic disabled, hence a route through Canada is definitely the fastest: *https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=42.33239,-83.04887&waypoint1=42.95594,-78.90584&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&app_id=______&app_code=____*

These places are just inside the US border. If I edit one co-ordinate to fall just inside the Canadian border, a route through Canada is recommended.

I can't find any restrictions that seem to be applied that would prevent routes going through Canada. I've tried examples in other countries which seem to be fine (e.g. a route starting and ending in Sweden was chosen to pass through Norway). What is going on here?

Comment: Might be because a password or enhanced ID would be required to cross the border?

Comment: Can you provide the example where it works for other country borders?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use fleet telematics with advance mapping options. Also if waypoint doesn't work, you can pass link ID or street to get the accurate result. please refer below documentation for more reference.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/api-reference.html

Also report the map team if the route is still incorrect using feedback API :

> developer.here.com/documentation/map-feedback/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-submit-feedback.html